# MAMP PRO crashes on launch (Monterey 12.0.1)

Tags: macos, mamp, macos-monterey

Not sure if it's the fault of the new system since I have seen others successfully run mamp pro from MacRumors.
And I have tried to give full disk access via system preference, also, I ran `sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/startApache.sh` in the terminal with no luck to fix.
From the problem report `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)`, I guess it's something about memory or index problem?

I don't know how to fix this problem, please help me,
here's the full crash report:

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               MAMP PRO [51611]
Path:                  /Applications/MAMP PRO.app/Contents/MacOS/MAMP PRO
Identifier:            de.appsolute.mamppro
Version:               6.6 (33836)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-10-26 12:26:16.4555 +0800
OS Version:            macOS 12.0.1 (21A559)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.0 (14Y908)
Anonymous UUID:        2F9EDB7E-C40F-322A-A424-13F4D70BBC05

Sleep/Wake UUID:       DF0A7272-42C0-43BE-A25D-C5F5AB3C5DF6

Time Awake Since Boot: 6500 seconds
Time Since Wake:       4085 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes:       KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00007ff8465e2450
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x00007ff8465e2450
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 10 Bus error: 10
Terminating Process:   exc handler [51611]

VM Region Info: 0x7ff8465e2450 is in 0x7ff8465e18a0-0x7ff84661bbd0;  bytes after start: 2992  bytes before end: 235391
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      unused shlib __TEXT      7ff8465e1898-7ff8465e18a0 [     8] r--/rw- SM=COW  ... this process
--->  __DATA_CONST             7ff8465e18a0-7ff84661bbd0 [  233K] r--/rw- SM=COW  ...aunchServices
      __DATA_CONST             7ff84661bbd0-7ff846658a48 [  244K] r--/rw- SM=COW  .../A/MetalTools

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libConfigurer64.dylib                  0x10d79faf8 0x10d77a000 + 154360
1   ???                                 0x7ff8890bc518 ???
2   libConfigurer64.dylib                  0x10d79f96d 0x10d77a000 + 153965
3   dyld                                   0x111648759 invocation function for block in dyld4::APIs::_dyld_register_func_for_add_image(void (*)(mach_header const*, long)) + 175
4   dyld                                   0x111630649 dyld4::RuntimeState::withLoadersReadLock(void () block_pointer) + 41
5   dyld                                   0x11164865a dyld4::APIs::_dyld_register_func_for_add_image(void (*)(mach_header const*, long)) + 116
6   libConfigurer64.dylib                  0x10d7a87d3 0x10d77a000 + 190419
7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7ff806767c6e load_images + 1546
8   dyld                                   0x11163541c dyld4::RuntimeState::notifyObjCInit(dyld4::Loader const*) + 170
9   dyld                                   0x11163abfd dyld4::Loader::runInitializersBottomUp(dyld4::RuntimeState&, dyld3::Array<dyld4::Loader const*>&) const + 167
10  dyld                                   0x11163abeb dyld4::Loader::runInitializersBottomUp(dyld4::RuntimeState&, dyld3::Array<dyld4::Loader const*>&) const + 149
11  dyld                                   0x11163abeb dyld4::Loader::runInitializersBottomUp(dyld4::RuntimeState&, dyld3::Array<dyld4::Loader const*>&) const + 149
12  dyld                                   0x11163acac dyld4::Loader::runInitializersBottomUpPlusUpwardLinks(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const + 108
13  dyld                                   0x11164e32e dyld4::APIs::runAllInitializersForMain() + 222
14  dyld                                   0x11162c358 dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*) + 3438
15  dyld                                   0x11162b4b4 start + 388

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8068cc00c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8068cc00c start_wqthread + 0


Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x000000010d79e91b  rbx: 0x0000000000000176  rcx: 0x00007ff8465e18a0  rdx: 0xffffffffffffffff
  rdi: 0x00007ff88b9b1a60  rsi: 0x0000600002c4866f  rbp: 0x00007ff7b35f90a0  rsp: 0x00007ff7b35f9030
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000990  r10: 0x0000000000000005  r11: 0x0000000000000005
  r12: 0x00007ff806e1a510  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x00007ff88b9b1a51  r15: 0x00006000008481e0
  rip: 0x000000010d79faf8  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x00007ff8465e2450
  
Logical CPU:     6
Error Code:      0x00000006 (no mapping for user data write)
Trap Number:     14

Thread 0 instruction stream:
  e1 48 8b 45 b8 48 8b 40-10 48 85 c0 4c 8b 65 c8  .H.E.H.@.H..L.e.
  4c 8b 7d a8 48 8b 5d c0-41 bd 00 00 00 80 75 a6  L.}.H.].A.....u.
  eb 4c 4b 8b 44 ef 10 48-85 c0 74 23 48 8b 4d d0  .LK.D..H..t#H.M.
  48 8b 55 c0 48 8b 0c d1-4b 3b 4c ef 08 4c 8b 65  H.U.H...K;L..L.e
  c8 74 10 48 89 08 48 8b-45 b8 4c 8b 38 eb 04 4c  .t.H..H.E.L.8..L
  8b 65 c8 4b 8b 44 ef 08-48 8b 4d d0 48 8b 5d c0  .e.K.D..H.M.H.].
 [48]89 04 d9 4c 8b 7d a8-41 bd 00 00 00 80 ff c3  H...L.}.A....... <==
  49 8b 44 24 28 48 c1 e8-03 48 39 d8 0f 87 e4 fe  I.D$(H...H9.....
  ff ff 48 83 c4 48 5b 41-5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f 5d  ..H..H[A\A]A^A_]
  c3 55 48 89 e5 48 89 f2-48 89 fe 48 8b 3d ae d5  .UH..H..H..H.=..
  08 00 5d e9 a3 fc ff ff-55 48 89 e5 41 57 41 56  ..].....UH..AWAV
  41 55 41 54 53 48 81 ec-b8 11 00 00 48 89 bd 30  AUATSH......H..0

Binary Images:
       0x10d77a000 -        0x10d829fff libConfigurer64.dylib (*) <ae387cc4-9425-3323-ac9f-ba486703833b> /Applications/MAMP PRO.app/Contents/Resources/libConfigurer64.dylib
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? (*) <00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000> ???
       0x111626000 -        0x111691fff dyld (*) <1a6ae033-9438-33c0-8077-988fd885250a> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7ff80675e000 -     0x7ff806797fff libobjc.A.dylib (*) <7cfcdc89-2bee-3784-b7af-c676f60fe211> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7ff8068ca000 -     0x7ff8068d5fff libsystem_pthread.dylib (*) <29a2750e-f31b-3630-8761-242a6bc3e99e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1.1G resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1.1G(100%)
Writable regions: Total=634.4M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=634.4M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                           240.1M       38 
MALLOC guard page                   16K        4 
MALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        3 
Stack                             9232K        3 
VM_ALLOCATE                          8K        2 
__DATA                            31.0M      457 
__DATA_CONST                      27.9M      298 
__DATA_DIRTY                      1535K      193 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       641.2M       10 
__OBJC_RO                         81.5M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         3120K        2 
__TEXT                           471.8M      501 
__UNICODE                          588K        1 
dyld private memory               1024K        1 
mapped file                       28.3M        2 
shared memory                       44K        4 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              1.9G     1524 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     1.6G     1524 



-----------
Full Report
-----------

{"app_name":"MAMP PRO","timestamp":"2021-10-26 12:26:16.00 +0800","app_version":"6.6","slice_uuid":"5878e976-c589-3c37-a57d-1944c5b9a8f5","build_version":"33836","platform":1,"bundleID":"de.appsolute.mamppro","share_with_app_devs":1,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 12.0.1 (21A559)","incident_id":"360E81F0-70F6-4779-A485-FE8587745FEF","name":"MAMP PRO"}
{
  "uptime" : 6500,
  "procLaunch" : "2021-10-26 12:26:16.2837 +0800",
  "procRole" : "Background",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "MacBookPro14,3",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 6564479054579,
  "coalitionID" : 1333,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 12.0.1",
    "build" : "21A559",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2021-10-26 12:26:16.4555 +0800",
  "incident" : "360E81F0-70F6-4779-A485-FE8587745FEF",
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "pid" : 51611,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 6564650188612,
  "cpuType" : "X86-64",
  "procName" : "MAMP PRO",
  "procPath" : "\/Applications\/MAMP PRO.app\/Contents\/MacOS\/MAMP PRO",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"6.6","CFBundleVersion":"33836","CFBundleIdentifier":"de.appsolute.mamppro"},
  "storeInfo" : {"deviceIdentifierForVendor":"4883B9B5-EDFA-5C8A-88FB-B55B61A3932A","thirdParty":true},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "de.appsolute.mamppro",
  "crashReporterKey" : "2F9EDB7E-C40F-322A-A424-13F4D70BBC05",
  "wakeTime" : 4085,
  "bridgeVersion" : {"build":"14Y908","train":"3.0"},
  "sleepWakeUUID" : "DF0A7272-42C0-43BE-A25D-C5F5AB3C5DF6",
  "sip" : "disabled",
  "vmRegionInfo" : "0x7ff8465e2450 is in 0x7ff8465e18a0-0x7ff84661bbd0;  bytes after start: 2992  bytes before end: 235391\n      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT\/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL\n      unused shlib __TEXT      7ff8465e1898-7ff8465e18a0 [     8] r--\/rw- SM=COW  ... this process\n--->  __DATA_CONST             7ff8465e18a0-7ff84661bbd0 [  233K] r--\/rw- SM=COW  ...aunchServices\n      __DATA_CONST             7ff84661bbd0-7ff846658a48 [  244K] r--\/rw- SM=COW  ...\/A\/MetalTools",
  "isCorpse" : 1,
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000002, 0x00007ff8465e2450","rawCodes":[2,140704309191760],"type":"EXC_BAD_ACCESS","signal":"SIGBUS","subtype":"KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00007ff8465e2450"},
  "termination" : {"flags":0,"code":10,"namespace":"SIGNAL","indicator":"Bus error: 10","byProc":"exc handler","byPid":51611},
  "vmregioninfo" : "0x7ff8465e2450 is in 0x7ff8465e18a0-0x7ff84661bbd0;  bytes after start: 2992  bytes before end: 235391\n      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT\/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL\n      unused shlib __TEXT      7ff8465e1898-7ff8465e18a0 [     8] r--\/rw- SM=COW  ... this process\n--->  __DATA_CONST             7ff8465e18a0-7ff84661bbd0 [  233K] r--\/rw- SM=COW  ...aunchServices\n      __DATA_CONST             7ff84661bbd0-7ff846658a48 [  244K] r--\/rw- SM=COW  ...\/A\/MetalTools",
  "extMods" : {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":0},
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  "threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":187807,"instructionState":{"instructionStream":{"bytes":[225,72,139,69,184,72,139,64,16,72,133,192,76,139,101,200,76,139,125,168,72,139,93,192,65,189,0,0,0,128,117,166,235,76,75,139,68,239,16,72,133,192,116,35,72,139,77,208,72,139,85,192,72,139,12,209,75,59,76,239,8,76,139,101,200,116,16,72,137,8,72,139,69,184,76,139,56,235,4,76,139,101,200,75,139,68,239,8,72,139,77,208,72,139,93,192,72,137,4,217,76,139,125,168,65,189,0,0,0,128,255,195,73,139,68,36,40,72,193,232,3,72,57,216,15,135,228,254,255,255,72,131,196,72,91,65,92,65,93,65,94,65,95,93,195,85,72,137,229,72,137,242,72,137,254,72,139,61,174,213,8,0,93,233,163,252,255,255,85,72,137,229,65,87,65,86,65,85,65,84,83,72,129,236,184,17,0,0,72,137,189,48],"offset":96}},"threadState":{"r13":{"value":0},"rax":{"value":4521060635},"rflags":{"value":66118},"cpu":{"value":6},"r14":{"value":140705470814801},"rsi":{"value":105553162700399},"r8":{"value":0},"cr2":{"value":140704309191760},"rdx":{"value":18446744073709551615},"r10":{"value":5},"r9":{"value":2448},"r15":{"value":105553124950496},"rbx":{"value":374},"trap":{"value":14,"description":"(no mapping for user data write)"},"err":{"value":6},"r11":{"value":5},"rip":{"value":4521065208,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"rbp":{"value":140701843034272},"rsp":{"value":140701843034160},"r12":{"value":140703244068112},"rcx":{"value":140704309188768},"flavor":"x86_THREAD_STATE","rdi":{"value":140705470814816}},"queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":154360,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":140705427866904,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":153965,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":141145,"symbol":"invocation function for block in dyld4::APIs::_dyld_register_func_for_add_image(void (*)(mach_header const*, long))","symbolLocation":175,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":42569,"symbol":"dyld4::RuntimeState::withLoadersReadLock(void () block_pointer)","symbolLocation":41,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":140890,"symbol":"dyld4::APIs::_dyld_register_func_for_add_image(void (*)(mach_header const*, long))","symbolLocation":116,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":190419,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":40046,"symbol":"load_images","symbolLocation":1546,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":62492,"symbol":"dyld4::RuntimeState::notifyObjCInit(dyld4::Loader const*)","symbolLocation":170,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":84989,"symbol":"dyld4::Loader::runInitializersBottomUp(dyld4::RuntimeState&, dyld3::Array<dyld4::Loader const*>&) const","symbolLocation":167,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":84971,"symbol":"dyld4::Loader::runInitializersBottomUp(dyld4::RuntimeState&, dyld3::Array<dyld4::Loader const*>&) const","symbolLocation":149,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":84971,"symbol":"dyld4::Loader::runInitializersBottomUp(dyld4::RuntimeState&, dyld3::Array<dyld4::Loader const*>&) const","symbolLocation":149,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":85164,"symbol":"dyld4::Loader::runInitializersBottomUpPlusUpwardLinks(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const","symbolLocation":108,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":164654,"symbol":"dyld4::APIs::runAllInitializersForMain()","symbolLocation":222,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":25432,"symbol":"dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*)","symbolLocation":3438,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":21684,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":388,"imageIndex":2}]},{"id":187837,"frames":[{"imageOffset":8204,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":4}]},{"id":187838,"frames":[{"imageOffset":8204,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":4}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 4520910848,
    "size" : 720896,
    "uuid" : "ae387cc4-9425-3323-ac9f-ba486703833b",
    "path" : "\/Applications\/MAMP PRO.app\/Contents\/Resources\/libConfigurer64.dylib",
    "name" : "libConfigurer64.dylib"
  },
  {
    "size" : 0,
    "source" : "A",
    "base" : 0,
    "uuid" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 4586627072,
    "size" : 442368,
    "uuid" : "1a6ae033-9438-33c0-8077-988fd885250a",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64h",
    "base" : 140703237005312,
    "size" : 237568,
    "uuid" : "7cfcdc89-2bee-3784-b7af-c676f60fe211",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/libobjc.A.dylib",
    "name" : "libobjc.A.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140703238496256,
    "size" : 49152,
    "uuid" : "29a2750e-f31b-3630-8761-242a6bc3e99e",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
  }
],
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 140703235268608,
  "size" : 15213641728,
  "uuid" : "3d05845f-3f65-358f-9ebf-2236e772ac01"
},
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1.1G resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1.1G(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=634.4M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=634.4M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nActivity Tracing                   256K        1 \nKernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 \nMALLOC                           240.1M       38 \nMALLOC guard page                   16K        4 \nMALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)\nSTACK GUARD                       56.0M        3 \nStack                             9232K        3 \nVM_ALLOCATE                          8K        2 \n__DATA                            31.0M      457 \n__DATA_CONST                      27.9M      298 \n__DATA_DIRTY                      1535K      193 \n__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       641.2M       10 \n__OBJC_RO                         81.5M        1 \n__OBJC_RW                         3120K        2 \n__TEXT                           471.8M      501 \n__UNICODE                          588K        1 \ndyld private memory               1024K        1 \nmapped file                       28.3M        2 \nshared memory                       44K        4 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              1.9G     1524 \nTOTAL, minus reserved VM space     1.6G     1524 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {
    "queue" : "com.apple.main-thread"
  }
},
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "607844aa04477260f58a8077",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_MORPHUN_ASSETS" : "60ef663fa2f864203caf575c"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 250000055
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "60da5e84ab0ca017dace9abf",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 250000007
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "60356660bbe37970735c5624",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 250000013
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "602ad4dac86151000cf27e46",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_DICTATION_ASSETS" : "6164895c201f677a9a4cb9e7"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 250000232
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "5fc94383418129005b4e9ae0",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 250000144
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "5ffde50ce2aacd000d47a95f",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 250000063
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "601d9415f79519000ccd4b69",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_TEXT_TO_SPEECH" : "61704b7f20024a1072784bb1"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 250000291
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [

  ]
}
}

Model: MacBookPro14,3, BootROM 447.40.12.0.0, 4 processors, Quad-Core Intel Core i7, 3.1 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.45f5
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 630, Intel HD Graphics 630, Built-In
Display: Color LCD, 2880 x 1800 Retina, Main, MirrorOff, Online
Graphics: Radeon Pro 560, Radeon Pro 560, PCIe, 4 GB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445424533303445422D45474347202020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445424533303445422D45474347202020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_wifi (0x14E4, 0x173), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.111.1 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1710.2)
AirPort: 
Bluetooth: Version (null), 0 services, 0 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB30Bus
USB Device: Apple T1 Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 41.5
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 41.5
```

Comment: Have you find any solution ?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hy, have you find the the solution? Please Update

Comment: It should be clear that any software containing `libConfigurer64.dylib` is cracked and not original. If it crashes, it's probably the fault of the hack.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded a new version of MAMP from this site - https://appstorrent.ru/269-mamp-pro.html

turned off the ISP. Instruction here - https://appstorrent.ru/510-sip.html

And MAMP started working (MacBook Pro m1. Monterey)

Comment: I tried this site either, but still with no luck, of course with ISP disabled, but thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

I face a similar issue, though I was not using pro. I could not even launch MAMP at all without a crash and error report like yours. My report was a little different, the reason was EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

I was able to determine the issue was MAMP trying to launch using nginx instead of apache. I opened the Applications > MAMP > conf folder and deleted the nginx folder and was then able to launch MAMP. Before starting the server I switched from nginx to apache, and it has worked since.

Comment: This solution worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the PRO feature of mamp isn't necessary for my personal use, but still I felt like building my host from scratch.
For those who don't want to spend time on this, try [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)
After some research, these are what I learned:

1. macOS has PHP and httpd(AKA apache) pre-installed
2. if you want to install the latest version you need brew installed
3. DIY an httpd.conf file needs some Googles, if you are not familiar with the computer and just want things to get to work, try XMAPP then.

Comment: In macOS 12+ (Monterey onwards): when you say "macOS has PHP and httpd(AKA apache) pre-installed", this is not correct:  (a) it DOES have Apache installed but (b) it does NOT have PHP installed, as it's been deprecated from this version onwards